# Add columns and values to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create an empty `pd.Dataframe()` and fill this in with a loop and add values to it. However, when I try this, it only fills in the column names and not the values. Normally, I fill in empty lists and in the end put everything in a `pd.DataFrame`, but this should be easier to do I think.

```
File = pd.read_excel("...//File.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0,len(File)):
    df['col1'] = (File.ix[i,1])  # Key(id) [0,1,2,3,4,5 etc]
    df['col2'] = (File.ix[i,2])  # Names 
    df['col3'] = (File.ix[i,3])  # Yes/No
    df['col4'] = (File.ix[i,4])  # Country
    df['col5'] = (File.ix[i,5])  # Language
    df['col6'] = (File.ix[i,6])  # Phone brand
```

Then I look at the DataFrame I see:

```
df.head()
Out[73]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6]
Index: []
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can't you just use `df = pd.read_excel(filename)`?

Comment: You initially created an empty df, when you try to create a new column and assign the row from another df, because the index label doesn't exist on the lhs no rows are added, also why call `read_excel` which gives you a df, and then read row by row? you can just do `df = File.ix[:, 1:6]`

Comment: Well I just want to use some of the columns and use the data later and then I can delete the Excel file which takes up memory. I can try your suggestion EdChum thanks

Comment: You should define your dataframe's columns before you add data. And check out the `append`-method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: I see you are reading excel file but In which part of your code you'r using your read excel file?

Comment: Everything below : for i in range.. when trying to append new columns to an empty dataframe.

Comment: I don't know If it's reading the excel file values correctly, you should try some trikes like  `File2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6], index= list("col1col2col3col4col5col6"))`
`df = pd.DataFrame({'':File, 'b':File2})`, I would like to ask you to upload your excel file to check something.